# withdraw my information from sql using ajax&js, dont know what's worng

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension (*freshment*) and have a little problem.
I have a button, and I want that when button is clicked, to show my information from my database on my extension page.

**HTML :**

```
<button class="button" id="show" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="myAjax()"><span>Show my purchaes</span></button>
<div id="showhere"> 
    //this is where i want to show the info
</div>
```

**Java Script :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://127.0.0.1/show.php",
            data:{ action:'showhere' },
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data) {
                ('#showhere').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    if($_POST['action'] == 'showhere') {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "********";
        $dbname = "test";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT ProductName, Amount, Date, WebStore FROM budget";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$row["ProductName"]."</td><td>".$row["Amount"]."</td><td>".$row["Date"]."</td><td>".$row["WebStore"]."</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

What I want it to do is pretty simple : I have a button and below I have a div called : "showhere", and in this div I want to take mysql info and write it.
your write i didnt write the exact problem, the problem is that the button doesnt do anything.

agian , thx!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: If this button is inside a popup of the extension toolbar icon, inline js like `onclick="myAjax()"` is not permitted. Use a separate js file with proper event listeners.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set it this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1/show.php",
      data: {
        action: 'showhere'
      },
      method: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        ('#showhere').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: raymond thx, but it still doesnt work, the proble is that nothing happens while im clicking the button.